# Clipping a UIView with a bezier path. BezierPath seems not to be applied completely

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath

I have to add a border with a wooden texture to a UIView. In order to do this I thought the following solution:

- I have the original UIView (say uiViewA)
- I create another UIView (say uiViewB) with the same size of the first one
- I create a bezier path with a 8px width
- Once created the path I apply this to uiViewB
- I add uiViewB to uiViewA's subviews

The code to apply the bezier path is the following:

```
UIView* uiViewB = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:uiViewA.bounds];
UIImage* wood = [UIImage imageNamed:@"texture_wood"];
[uiViewB setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:wood]];

// creation of the bezier path
UIBezierPath* borderPath = ... ;
[borderPath setLineWidth:8.0];
[borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
borderPath addLineToPoint:...
borderPath addArcWithCenter:...
borderPath addLineToPoint:...
borderPath addArcWithCenter:...
borderPath addLineToPoint:...

CAShapeLayer* borderMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[borderMaskLayer setFrame:uiViewA.bounds];
borderMaskLayer.path = [borderPath CGPath];
uiViewB.layer.mask = borderMaskLayer;
[uiViewB.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

[image]

But the result I obtain is the following:

[image]

Do you have any idea of why bezier path seems not to be applied in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you have there it looks like you are using the default fill and stroke of the shape layer that is used as a mask, thus the path is filled and you get the result that you are seeing.

What you want to do is set a clear fill color and set some random opaque stroke color. Then you will have to set an appropriate line width, line cap, line round, etc. to configure how the stroke looks.